# Ceiling Mounted Camera Slider with Pan

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stepper-motor, linear-motion

I am looking for feedback on my camera rig design. I am going to run a track along the ceiling of my studio to move my camera back in forth. I also want the camera to be able to pan, so I want to incorporate one of my spare nema 17 stepper motors. Below is a rough sketch of my proposed design.

A couple concerns I have:
1. Is this too much axial load on the stepper motor shaft? The camera weighs about 2.5 lbs including the housing that will attach to the flange.
2. The flange is attached to the stepper motor by a set screw. I do not want the safety of my camera to rely on a set screw as this is mounted from the ceiling.

Any design suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have the stepper motor turn a worm and a gear with the shaft (with a decent fixing) supported on a bearing to hang the camera from. The worm and gear will also give more control over the rotation of the motor relative to the camera.

[image]